# Solve for launch angle in projectile motion equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

I need help solving the projectile motion equation for $\theta$.
The projectile motion equation is

$$
y = \tan(\theta)x - \frac{gx^2}{2v_0^2\cos^2(\theta)}.
$$

How do we solve it so that $\theta$ is alone on one side?

Comment: Shouldn't the equation be? $$y=x \tan \theta - \frac{g x^2}{2 v_0^2 \cos^2 \theta} $$

Comment: What makes you think that you *can* solve for $\theta$? You can't always do that. A simple example is $x = A \sin(x)$; you cannot solve this for $x$ in the way you're asking.

Comment: @ja72, yes, the original equation is what you said it was.  The new equation doesn't have the right units.

Answer (score 1):

Make $z = \tan \theta$ and solve for $z$

$$ y = x z - \frac{g x^2 (1+z^2)}{2 v_0^2} $$

I got

$$ \theta = \arctan \left( \frac{v_0^2}{g x} \pm \sqrt{\frac{v_0^2 (v_0^2-2 g y)}{g^2 x^2}-1} \right) $$

---

*Hint*: $1 + \tan^2 x = \frac{1}{\cos^2 x}$